# How can I add color to my cucumber test results in Terminal using autotest?

Tags: terminal, cucumber, autotest

I am not getting any color in my Cucumber tests. I hope there is a way to make Cucumber output colorful results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [wiki article](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Console-Colours) on adjusting the console colors for Cucumber.  As mentioned in that article, you can see what colors can be used in your terminal by issuing the following command:

```
ruby -e "require 'rubygems'; require 'term/ansicolor'; puts Term::ANSIColor.attributes"
```

*Update*

Refer to [this page](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Autotest-Integration) for some documentation on getting the Cucumber colors to work while using autotest.